# Using a smart "CRUD style" picker for a single field in Play! Framework

Tags: java, playframework, crud

I have a custom edit form for some entity (not based on the CRUD module), and I would like to use a CRUD-like editor for just one specific field.

Specifically, it's one of the fields that is actually a @ManyToOne relation to another entity:

```
public class Person extends Model {
  public String name;

  @ManyToOne
  public School school;  // School also extends Model

  ...
}
```

How do I generate an editor/picker for this specific field, while still not requiring me to extend the CRUD class or change anything else about my view form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [select tag](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/tags#select). The code should be something like:

```
#{select 'schools', items:models.School.all(), valueProperty:'id', labelProperty:'name', value:<selected_id>, class:'myCssClass', id:'schools' /}
```

That should generate the dropdown you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

The more general answer is:

1. Open form.html file from CRUD module.
2. Pick the right template for you field type. For example:

   ## {crud.textField name:'user.email' /}